# Android Time Ago from Date String?

Tags: android

i just implement this library https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago in my ListView.

I want to convert date string each item like format 2015-08-12 01:01:03 , so how to set it ?

thanks, sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public String convert(Date datetime) {
    return df.format(datetime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to convert your date string into a long in milliseconds since epoch format. Check this [github issue](https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago/issues/19#issuecomment-119430326) for more details.